# Error Page Not Found when I update records in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am new with django and  I try to create a simple form to update some records.

models.py

```
class ConfigForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self,idprov,*args,**kwargs):
        super(ConfigForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.id_proveedor = idprov

    class Meta:
        model = Config
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def configView(request):
    pk = request.POST.get('idprov')
    prov = get_object_or_404(Config, id_proveedor=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = ConfigForm(request.POST, instance = prov)
       if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
    else:
       form = ConfigForm(Request.POST, instance = prov )
    return render_to_response('config.html',{'form':form},RequestContext(request))
```

My updateform.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<form method='POST' action='' class='form'>
   <div class="form-group">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
   </div>
        <button type='submit' class="btn btn-primary">Grabar</button>
</form
{% endblock %}
```

I pass the id from other form and works fine.
But when I press the button save the next error is displayed:

```
 Page not found (404) Request Method: POST Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8080/config/

 No Config matches the given query.
```

I don't know where is the error.
The error only appear when I try to save the changes
Help please

Thanks in advance

Comment: Once the form is submitted, the next time the page is loaded, it is a get request, and `pk = request.POST.get('idprov')` evaluates to `None`, which is the cause of the issue. To verify, just `print pk` after this line, and you will see that it is `None`

Comment: @Karth1kr Thanks, I see your point but I want redirect to the main page of the application and always appear the same error.

Comment: That is because you do not have a redirect after the `form.save` and the same page is reloaded.

Comment: I put return HttpResponseRedirect('/index/') and nothing happen, always the same error

Answer (score 0):

The 404 page comes from this line:

```
get_object_or_404(Config, id_proveedor=pk)
```

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) states that

`Calls get() on a given model manager, but it raises Http404 instead of the model’s DoesNotExist exception.`

You're getting the 404 because you don't have a matching model.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but If I remove that i can get the data of the selected provider. I follow the documentation and try to use the queryset and other errors appear. how can I retrieve the data without using get_object_or_404

Comment: `Config.objects.get(id_proveedor=pk)` should do it.

Comment: sorry bother you, I follow your advice and work but when I press the button save another error appear DoesNotExist at /config/
Config matching query does not exist. I only want when I hit the save button redirect me to the index page. and Thanks for evetything, very helpful

Comment: `DoesNotExist` means that you don't have a matching model for the data you're supplying to the `get()` call.

Comment: But I only trying to update a field different from the Id, I don't understand. I only have one record in that table. how can I update.I need to rewrite all the view, I am very confused because I know that model and records exists

Comment: If you just have 1 record in the table, use `Config.objects.first()` to get it.